# Remember reading pane view size in Outlook

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

With the reading pane, I often resize the vertical line to the right to give more space for my message on the left as the below snapshot.

When I restart the application, I always have to resize it. Why? How can I get it remember its position?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too was having the same issue and found the solution by accident. Please follow the steps below:

1. Set the splitter to the position you desire
2. Exit from Outlook
3. Open Outlook

The splitter's position will now be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the trick here successfully https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/442895-how-to-permanently-size-the-outlook-2013-window.

Open your Outlook, resize and make the layout as your wish. Then hold CTRL and click the X button to close it. Then reopen your Outlook.

Good luck.